# AWS CloudFormation stack: API Gateway resource with nested paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway resource manually built that looks like:

```
GET
  /assets/{items} - (points to S3 bucket)
  /{proxy+} - points to Lambda function
```

[image]

I would like to mimic this setup in a Cloudformation YAML template but unsure how to do so. Here is the current template I'm working with (partially reduced for brevity):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  apiGatewayStageName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
    Default: call
  lambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
    Default: my-function
  s3BucketName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name: my-api
      Description: My API
    Metadata:
      ...
  apiGatewayRootMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
    Metadata:
      ...
  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment'
    DependsOn:
      - apiGatewayRootMethod
      - apiGatewayGETMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: !Ref apiGatewayStageName
    Metadata:
      ...
  lambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      ...
  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    ...
  lambdaIAMRole:
    ...
  lambdaLogGroup:
    ...
  apiGatewayGETMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 1a329c4d-9d18-499e-b852-0e361af324f4
  s3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref s3BucketName
    Metadata:
      ...
Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub >-
      https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}
  lambdaArn:
    Value: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
```

That is the result of lots of tweaking and me not having any prior CloudFormation knowledge besides going over the official docs. When the stack behind that template gets created, its API Gateway resource looks like:
[image]

The POST action is unnecessary, and only there from trial and error. The GET resource is the only important one as application returned by the Lambda function isn't doing any post requests yet.

The GET one must be created from this portion of the Stack:

```
apiGatewayGETMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
```

What must be done to make it so that GET resource has the nested `/assets/{items}` path pointing to an S3 bucket and the `{proxy+}` path pointing to a Lambda? Do I need to specify separate sibling resources for those paths like `apiGatewayAssets` and `apiGatewayLambdaProxy` then connect them to `apiGatewayGETMethod` somehow?

**2020-05-17 Update**

The current part tripping me up is this resource:

```
apiGatewayAssetsItemsResourceMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayAssetsItemsResource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        Credentials: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/AnExistingRole
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.item: 'method.request.path.item'
          method.request.path.item: true
        Uri: !Sub >-
          arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:s3:path/${s3BucketName}/{item}
```

That leads to a CloudFormation stack creation error with the status reason being `Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.path.item] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: XXXXXX)`

However, if I attempt to create it with the exact same resource minus the `RequestParameters` entry, it gets created successfully. Although when viewing that API Gateway GET method in the console, it's missing the `Paths: item` line inside the Integration Request box. Full template I'm currently using:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  apiGatewayStageName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
    Default: call
  lambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
    Default: my-function
  s3BucketName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name: my-api
      Description: My API
  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment'
    DependsOn:
      - apiGatewayGETMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: !Ref apiGatewayStageName
  lambdaFunction:
    ...
  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    ...
  lambdaIAMRole:
    ...
  lambdaLogGroup:
    ...
  apiGatewayGETMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
  s3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref s3BucketName
  BucketPolicy:
    ...
  apiGatewayAssetsResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      ParentId: !GetAtt 
        - apiGateway
        - RootResourceId
      PathPart: assets
  apiGatewayAssetsItemsResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      PathPart: '{item}'
      ParentId: !Ref apiGatewayAssetsResource
  apiGatewayAssetsItemsResourceMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayAssetsItemsResource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        Credentials: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/AnExistingRole
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        Uri: !Sub >-
          arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:s3:path/${s3BucketName}/{item}
  apiGatewayLambdaResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
      ParentId: !GetAtt 
        - apiGateway
        - RootResourceId
  apiGatewayLambdaResourceMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayLambdaResource
      HttpMethod: ANY
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub >-
      https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}
  lambdaArn:
    Value: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
```

Comment: You use different integration methods. In top image you use AWS, while in the lower one you have AWS_PROXY. So obviously you can't mining them. So either create both as AWS, or as AWS_PROXY.

Comment: Please can you share the final working template for other people, thanks!

Comment: @pho_pho you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/PatNeedham/5b3c4b68997b0375f27d402a056a6e1b

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and for sharing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you need to do for this is the following:

- Create a AWS::ApiGateway::Resource with a PathPart of `assets`, this will use a ParentId of the RootResourceId attr from your Rest API
- Create a AWS::ApiGateway::Resource with a PathPart of `{item}`, this will use a ParentId of the assets Resource above.
- Create a AWS::ApiGateway::Method for the ResourceId of the resource above. This will use the `HTTP_PROXY` and set the Uri to be the S3 bucket path, making sure to include the `{{ item }}` variable in the path.
- Create a AWS::ApiGateway::Resource with a PathPart of `{proxy+}`, this will use a ParentId of the RootResourceId attr from your Rest API
- Create a AWS::ApiGateway::Method for the ResourceId of the resource above. This will use the `AWS_PROXY` and set the uri to reference the Lambda function.

Hope this helps

Comment: For the 3rd bullet point listed, I have a resource defined with `Properties.Integration.Type` set to `HTTP_PROXY`, and for the `Properties.Integration.Uri` field I set it to `arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:s3:path/${s3BucketName}/{{item}}` but during creation it fails with message "Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: XXXXXX"

Comment: Also tried with the Uri ending in `/{item}` , which led to the same outcome

Comment: I also tried to give the Uri a value of `arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:s3:path/${s3BucketName}`, after finding a mention of `arn:aws:apigateway:api-region:s3:path/{bucket}` on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-request-basic-setup.html, but still the same outcome. Is there some sort of Uri validator? When viewing that stack on the CloudFormation Designer page, clicking the checkmark led to "Template is valid."

Comment: So I think I figured out the uri part by giving it: `Uri: !Sub >-
          arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:s3:path/${s3BucketName}/{item}` - no more complaints in the CF console now for that, however, for `RequestParameters` field I'm giving it one key/value pair, with the key `integration.request.path.item` and value `true` but it complains "Invalid mapping expression specified: true" - also tried setting the value as 'method.request.path.item', though same error

Comment: For HTTP proxy it can just be the URL i.e. of the S3 bucket, that would suffice

Comment: And for the last it should be equal to method.request.path.item

Comment: I tried the key/value pair like `integration.request.path.item: method.request.path.item` (without the value in quotes this time) which led to "Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.path.item] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: XXXXXX"

Comment: Also add on the method a RequestParameter to the same method with `method.request.path.item` set to true

Comment: Is there a different error? Could you repost your CloudFormation now? :)

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question to include the full template I'm now using, or at least the full parts of the API Gateway resources in question

Comment: Hi so, add the RequestParameters to the Method, not the integration parameter and add the method.request.path.item set to true on that, then in the integration parameter add the RequestParameters attribute that sets integration.request.path.item equal to method.request.path.item

Comment: So https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters is where the method.request.path.item is set to true and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-requestparameters for the integration.request.path.item

Comment: That did it! You are the best!

Comment: No problem, glad i helped

Comment: Thank you @PamelaPereyra :)

Comment: can you share the final working template, that would help me !!!!